# Pcap.Net Handling offline trace file with OffLinePacketDevice

Tags: c#, pcap.net

The situation:

I am working on a tool that simulates a device, based on its actual network data that I captured earlier with WireShark.
The captured data is from a production device that I need to recreate in a debug enviroment.

What I need is a way to read packets from the trace file and in a sort of 'real time', and then handle and alter the packets and resend it, as if the device was present in my debug environment.

The problem:

I am using the (2nd) example from the page [github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Handling-offline-dump-files](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Handling-offline-dump-files). 
This example shows Pcap.Net using OffLinePacketDevice to read the dump file and handle the packets.

My problem is that the packets do not get handled in a timed fashion. The trace holds several minutes of data, but is processed in a few seconds.

I have tried this example before and then it seemed to react just as I expected.

So, my question is: Should the behavior be automatically timed? 
If so, then I broke something (but what?). 
If not, then I have to add some sleep mechanism (not too difficult).

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pcap.Net's Send Buffer to send packets while respecting their timestamps.

So you read the packets from the offline dump, alter them, insert them to a Send Buffer and transmit them.

Links:

- [Reading packets from offline dump](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Handling-offline-dump-files#reading-packets-from-a-dump-file)
- [Generating packets (code in the send packets guide)](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Sending-Packets#sending-a-single-packet-with-sendpacket)
- [Sending packets using a Send Buffer](https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Sending-Packets#sending-packets-using-send-buffer)